# adding boulders to pygame snake in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i have a snake game i made in python and i want to add him boulders that will appear every 10 "apples" he gets, so can you help me please? this is the code right now

```
import pygame
import random
__author__ = 'Kfir_Kahanov'
init = pygame.init()


def quit_game():
    """
    this function will quit the game
    :return:
    """
    pygame.quit()
    quit()


# this will set a nice sound when the player gets an apple
BLOP = pygame.mixer.Sound("Blop.wav")
pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(BLOP, 1.0)
volume = pygame.mixer.Sound.get_volume(BLOP)
# making colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 155, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (217, 217, 0)
SNAKE_RED = (152, 2, 2)


def display_fill():
    """
    this will fill the screen with a color of my choice
    :return:
    """
    game_display.fill(GREEN)


def mute():
    """
    this will mute the game or unmute it
    :return:
    """
    if volume == 1.0:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(BLOP, 0.0)
    else:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(BLOP, 10.0)


# all the pygame stuff for the display
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("The hungry Cobra")
ICON = pygame.image.load("apple_icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(ICON)
pygame.display.update()

# deciding on FPS, the size of the snake, apples, and making the fonts for the text

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
BLOCK_SIZE = 20
APPLE_THICKNESS = 30
fps = 15
# BOULDER_THICKNESS = 30

direction = "right"  # deciding the starting direction
tiny_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 10)
small_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
med_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
large_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)


def text_objects(text, color, size):
    """
    defining the text
    :param text:
    :param color:
    :param size:
    :return:
    """
    global text_surface
    if size == "tiny":
        text_surface = tiny_font.render(text, True, color)
    if size == "small":
        text_surface = small_font.render(text, True, color)

    if size == "medium":
        text_surface = med_font.render(text, True, color)

    if size == "large":
        text_surface = large_font.render(text, True, color)
    return text_surface, text_surface.get_rect()


# loading apple and snake img
IMG = pygame.image.load("snake_head.png")
APPLE_IMG = pygame.image.load("apple_icon.png")


# BOULDER_IMG = pygame.image.load("boulder.png")


def rand_apple_gen():
    """
    making apple function
    :return:
    """
    rand_apple_x = round(random.randrange(10, DISPLAY_WIDTH - APPLE_THICKNESS))  # / 10.0 * 10.0
    rand_apple_y = round(random.randrange(10, DISPLAY_HEIGHT - APPLE_THICKNESS))  # / 10.0 * 10.0
    return rand_apple_x, rand_apple_y


"""
def rand_boulder_gen():

    making the boulder parameters
    :return:

    rand_boulder_x = round(random.randrange(10, DISPLAY_WIDTH - BOULDER_THICKNESS))
    rand_boulder_y = round(random.randrange(10, DISPLAY_WIDTH - BOULDER_THICKNESS))
    return rand_boulder_x, rand_boulder_y
    """


def message(msg, color, y_displace=0, size="small"):
    """
    making a function for the making of the text
    :param msg:
    :param color:
    :param y_displace:
    :param size:
    :return:
    """
    text_surf, text_rect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    text_rect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH / 2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT / 2) + y_displace)
    game_display.blit(text_surf, text_rect)


def intro_message():
    """
    making the intro
    :return:
    """
    intro = True
    while intro:
        display_fill()
        message("Welcome to ", BLACK, -200, "large")
        message("The hungry Cobra!", BLACK, -100, "large")
        message("Eat apples to grow, but be care full", BLACK)
        message("if you run into yourself or outside the screen", BLACK, 30)
        message("you gonna have a bad time", BLACK, 60)
        message("Press S to start or E to exit", BLACK, 90)
        message("Created by Kfir Kahanov", BLACK, 200, "tiny")
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                display_fill()
                pygame.display.update()
                quit_game()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                    mute()
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    intro = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    display_fill()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    quit_game()


score_edit = 0


def score_f(score):
    """
    making a score_f on the top left
    :param score:
    :return:
    """
    text = small_font.render("Score:" + str(score + score_edit), True, YELLOW)
    game_display.blit(text, [0, 0])


def pause_f():
    """
    making a pause_f screen
    :return:
    """
    pause = True
    if pause:
        message("Paused", RED, -50, "large")
        message("Press R to start over, E to exit or C to continue", BLACK)
        pygame.display.update()

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                display_fill()
                pygame.display.update()
                quit_game()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                    mute()
                if event.key == pygame.K_c or pygame.K_ESCAPE or pygame.K_p:
                    pause = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    global score_edit, direction, cheat1, cheat4, cheat3, cheat2
                    direction = "right"
                    score_edit = 0
                    cheat1 = 16
                    cheat2 = 16
                    cheat3 = 16
                    cheat4 = 16
                    game_loop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    display_fill()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    quit_game()

        CLOCK.tick(5)


# making cheats
cheat1 = 16
cheat2 = 16
cheat3 = 16
cheat4 = 16


def snake(snake_list):
    """
    defining the snake head
    :param snake_list:
    :return:
    """
    global head
    if direction == "right":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 270)
    elif direction == "left":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 90)
    elif direction == "down":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 180)
    elif direction == "up":
        head = IMG

    game_display.blit(head, (snake_list[-1][0], snake_list[-1][1]))

    for x_n_y in snake_list[:-1]:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, SNAKE_RED, [x_n_y[0], x_n_y[1], BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE])


def game_loop():
    """
    this will be the game itself
    :return:
    """
    global cheat1
    global cheat2
    global cheat3
    global cheat4
    global direction
    global fps
    game_exit = False
    game_over = False
    global score_edit
    lead_x = DISPLAY_WIDTH / 2
    lead_y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT / 2
    # rand_boulder_x, rand_boulder_y = -50, -50
    lead_x_change = 10
    lead_y_change = 0
    snake_list = []
    snake_length = 1
    rand_apple_x, rand_apple_y = rand_apple_gen()

    while not game_exit:
        if game_over:
            message("Game over!", RED, -50, "large")
            message("Press E to exit or R to retry.", BLACK, 20, "medium")
            pygame.display.update()
        while game_over:
            fps = 15

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    game_exit = True
                    game_over = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                        mute()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                        game_exit = True
                        game_over = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        direction = "right"
                        score_edit = 0
                        cheat1 = 16
                        cheat2 = 16
                        cheat3 = 16
                        cheat4 = 16
                        game_loop()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                    mute()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and lead_x_change is not BLOCK_SIZE and direction is not "right":
                    lead_x_change = -BLOCK_SIZE
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    direction = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and lead_x_change is not -BLOCK_SIZE and direction is not "left":
                    lead_x_change = BLOCK_SIZE
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    direction = "right"

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and lead_y_change is not BLOCK_SIZE and direction is not "down":
                    lead_y_change = -BLOCK_SIZE
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    direction = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and lead_y_change is not -BLOCK_SIZE and direction is not "up":
                    lead_y_change = BLOCK_SIZE
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    direction = "down"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause_f()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause_f()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_k:  # the cheat
                    cheat1 = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                    cheat2 = 4
                elif event.key == pygame.K_i:
                    cheat3 = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    cheat4 = 3
                elif cheat1 == 0 and cheat2 == 4 and cheat3 == 0 and cheat4 == 3:
                    score_edit = 10000
        if lead_x >= DISPLAY_WIDTH or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT or lead_y < 0:
            game_over = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        display_fill()

        game_display.blit(APPLE_IMG, (rand_apple_x, rand_apple_y))

        snake_head = [lead_x, lead_y]
        snake_list.append(snake_head)
        if len(snake_list) > snake_length:
            del snake_list[0]
        for eachSegment in snake_list[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == snake_head:
                game_over = True

        snake(snake_list)
        score_f(snake_length * 10 - 10)

        pygame.display.update()

        if rand_apple_x < lead_x < rand_apple_x + APPLE_THICKNESS or rand_apple_x < lead_x + BLOCK_SIZE < rand_apple_x \
                + APPLE_THICKNESS:
            if rand_apple_y < lead_y < rand_apple_y + APPLE_THICKNESS or rand_apple_y < lead_y + BLOCK_SIZE < \
                    rand_apple_y + APPLE_THICKNESS:
                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(BLOP)
                rand_apple_x, rand_apple_y = rand_apple_gen()
                snake_length += 1
                fps += 0.15
                """
                if snake_length * 10 - 10 == 20:
                    rand_boulder_x, rand_boulder_y = rand_boulder_gen()
                    game_display.blit(BOULDER_IMG, (rand_boulder_x, rand_boulder_y))



        elif rand_boulder_x < lead_x < rand_boulder_y + BOULDER_THICKNESS or rand_boulder_x < lead_x + BLOCK_SIZE < \
                rand_boulder_x + BOULDER_THICKNESS:
            if rand_boulder_x < lead_y < rand_boulder_y + BOULDER_THICKNESS or rand_boulder_y < lead_y + BLOCK_SIZE < \
                    rand_boulder_y + BOULDER_THICKNESS:
                game_over = True
                """
        CLOCK.tick(fps)
    display_fill()

pygame.display.update()
quit_game()


intro_message()
game_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try explaining what you have tried and why it isn't working. You would get better help that way.

From what I can see from your code though....

You seem to be on the right track in your commented out code. Evaluating the snake length or score variable during your game loop, then generating a random boulder to the screen. The next step is just handling the collision logic for all the boulders, which I see two ways of doing. First way is creating a lists of the boulder attributes like the x,y positions, similar to how you did the snake list. The second way would be to create a class for boulders, then when the score, or snake length, reaches 10, create a new boulder object. Using a class may make the collision logic much easier to handle.

Comment: one of my problems it that the boulder wont appear on screen when it sopposed to do you have a way to fix it?